# php laravel blade file Auth::check is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `Auth::check` function in laravel. In all controller its working fine but in blade file it will not working.

I got this error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 FatalErrorException in
>   /var/www/html/laravel-master/storage/framework/views/e016f9336e75e5cb0b189c91cd736729b7184a61.php
>   line 5: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::check()
>   in e016f9336e75e5cb0b189c91cd736729b7184a61.php line 5

My blade file auth check code is

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <div class="dispayingTextDiv"></div>
@endif
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Syntaxt error. There is no ')' after Auth::check().

Comment: Sorry i edited please seen my code again. My error is true

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try use: `auth()->check()`, `\Auth::check()`, or remove all views in `/var/www/html/laravel-master/storage/framework/views/`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this method

```
@guest
    // Show content if  unauthenticated
@endguest

@auth
    // The data only available for auth user
@endauth
```

Answer (score 3):

**Auth :-**

You can check as follows (5.5+)

```
@auth
  //your code 
@endauth
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Auth::check()` does not work, use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check()` instead:

```
@if(Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check())
    <div class="dispayingTextDiv"></div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

For unauthenticated you can use

```js
@guest
// Show case unauthenticated
@endguest
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.

Comment: but this is understandable for a regular laravel user

Answer (score 1):

You can use blade directives take a [look](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#control-structures)

```
@auth
// The user is authenticated...
@endauth
```